# How do you "colcon build" with a specific C++ version?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Problem (TL;DR)

How do I run `colcon build` with the C++ version set specifically to 17, and without having to manually edit every CMakeList file in my system?

### Problem (in detail)

I am currently encountering a problem whilst compiling on a Ubuntu 20 system, with ROS Galactic and ROS2 Foxy both installed. I want to compile my ROS2 code using Galactic (not Foxy) so I have made sure that I have sourced only the setup file for that distro. But when I run `colcon build` I get a nebulous error that suggests the problem is that a pre-C++17 standard is being used:

```
/opt/ros/galactic/include/rclcpp/any_subscription_callback.hpp:81:29: error: ‘variant’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a 
template type
   81 |   using variant_type = std::variant<
      |                             ^~~~~~~
/opt/ros/galactic/include/rclcpp/any_subscription_callback.hpp:81:24: note: ‘std::variant’ is only available from C++17 onwards
   81 |   using variant_type = std::variant<
      |                        ^~~
```

This error doesn't reference any of my code directly, and seems to indicate that the rclcpp package in Galactic is failing to compile because C++17 isn't being used. I'm surprised by this as there are a a few posts around the place suggesting that Galactic requires C++17 ([see here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-compatibility-with-c-20/19014)) but I couldn't find any reference to this on the [Galactic release page](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone.html). This also doesn't appear to be a known issue with rclcpp ([see the issue tracker](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues?q=is%3Aissue+std%3A%3Avariant))

I couldn't find any reference to "CXX" or "C++" versions in the [colcon documentation](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/index.html) either, but through `colcon build help` figured out that the following command should in *theory* set the C++ version:

```
$ colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++17'
```

However this doesn't appear to work as I get the same error. I know that I *can* force individual packages to compile with a specific version using this code snippet in the CMakeList file:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()
```

However, I would rather not have to change the CMakeList files of all the packages in my codebase, and I'm pretty sure that changing the version via `colcon build` should have worked. So my questions are:

1. How do you force colcon to use a specific C++ standard?
2. Why didn't setting it via `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++17'`  work?
3. If this isn't the solution to the std::variant build error, can someone please point me in the direction of the solution?

I suspect that the cause of the std::variant build error has something to do with the fact that I have Foxy installed on the same system. But I haven't worked out why yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384114/how-do-you-%22colcon-build%22-with-a-specific-c++-version?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-10**:\

> a Ubuntu 20 system, with ROS Galactic and ROS2 Foxy both installed

how did you install ROS?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-12**:
Docker container with an image pulled from osrf/ros:foxy-desktop or osrf/ros:galactic-desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you already know, asking multiple questions in a single post is not really a good idea, so:

> If this isn't the solution to the std::variant build error, can someone please point me in the direction of the solution?

this would seem to be the actual question.

With the information in your current post I can't say what is causing your problem.

`rclcpp` on Galactic already sets the C++ version to 17 (from [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/910cf32489bbb0d4b935d2156b2ce42faa4ec2a4/rclcpp/CMakeLists.txt#L25-L28)):

> ```
> # Default to C++17
> ```

```
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()
```

You should not need to change anything there.

To see what's happening, you could try to see what <del>Colcon</del> CMake is actually executing with:

```
colcon build \
  --event-handlers console_direct+ \
  --cmake-args \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
```

(and perhaps a `--packages-up-to` or `--packages-select` to avoid trying to build everything)

That could give you a clue as to which exact commands are being executed.

Having written that: overriding the specific C++ standard for a CMake project isn't really anything specific to Colcon, but more a CMake "thing".

You don't set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to `-std=c++17`, but set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to `17` directly.

I would expect the command you show to work with that one change (I like to split things across multiple lines for readability, this is still just a single command):

```
colcon build \
  --cmake-args \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
```

(make sure to remove the `build` directory from your workspace to avoid CMake caching things)

If it still doesn't work, that would imply something else is wrong.

PS: note that if you'd like to build only specific packages with specific `cmake-args`, you'd use a [Colcon meta file](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#meta-files). The command line as proposed by you will apply to *all* packages built by that specific Colcon invocation.

> I'm surprised by this as there are a a few posts around the place suggesting that Galactic requires C++17 ([see here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-compatibility-with-c-20/19014)) but I couldn't find any reference to this on the [Galactic release page](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone.html).

It's stated here, in [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms: Galactic Geochelone (May 2021 - November 2022)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#galactic-geochelone-may-2021-november-2022):

> Minimum language requirements:
>
> - C++17

as well as on the Galactic version of the [Code style and language versions](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Contributing/Code-Style-Language-Versions.html#id2) page:

> **Standard**
>
> Galactic targets C++17.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-11**:
Thanks for the help gvdhoorn! You're right, I probably should have separated this into two questions. I was in a rush and got lazy. Building with C++17 did solve the problem though!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-12**:
So are you enabling C++17 in your *own* package(s)?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-12**:
Not initially, as my own packages only require C++11 or 14.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-12**:
Then how would you `#include` a header which does require C++17?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-12**:
Well, the contents of my packages don't require C++17, but many have use a similar snippet of code to what you posted in your answer in their CMakeLists file to set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to C++14.

When I posted this question I didn't understand how this error could be occurring. But looking back through my code and your answer, what I think has happened is those code snippets have set the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to 14. I assume that this is a global flag, so when those packages include various `rclcpp` headers from (in this case) Galactic, that C++ standard is applied to the compilation of those Galactic headers (which need C++17 minimum). My CMake knowledge is pretty patchy in this area, so please correct me if any of this is wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-12**:\

> I assume that this is a global flag

no, it's per-package, local only.

CMake projects can export that requirement using `target_compile_features(..)`, but you must link to such projects / libraries using `target_link_libraries(..)` and I'm not exactly sure (any more) whether Ament doesn't interfere there.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-12**:
Ah, there goes my theory then. Ament causing extra complication is entirely possible, since I've been using `ament_auto` a lot to try and simplify my CMakeList files.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-12**:
Just to clarify: it's local in the sense it's not automatically exported to other packages.

But if you set a specific standard for your package, and then include headers from other projects, *those headers* will be `#include`d by the compiler under the standard you've set for *your* package.

So this:

> when those packages include various `rclcpp` headers from (in this case) Galactic, that C++ standard is applied to the compilation of those Galactic headers (which need C++17 minimum)

is essentially correct (ie: C++17-requiring headers are interpreted as C++14 due to your local standard selection).

That was also why I asked:

> Then how would you `#include` a header which does require C++17?

However, if a CMake project uses `target_compile_features(..)` and exports that target, your local C++14 would be overridden by the C++17 of the target you `target_link_libraries(..)` against.

But again, that's plain CMake. I've not verified whether Ament respects all of that.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-12**:
Ah, I think I see. I appreciate the thorough explanation, and it gives me a few places to start for further reading.